# Using shared libraries to run bitcoin-qt / litecoin-qt

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking

I am receiving the following error when I'm trying to run the compiled `litecoin-qt`,

```
Error while loading shared libraries: libdb_cxx-4.8.so: cannot open shared object file
```

How do I make a new path for the berkeley lib?

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"
```

Is it somewhere in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`? If so, what command should I run?

Whenever I try to find where `libdb_cxx-4.8.so` is installed,

```
$ whereis libdb_cxx-4.8.so
```

The output is just this,

```
libdb_cxx-4.8:
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: find / | grep libdb_cxx-4.8.so  Can you do this and show us where is libdb?

Comment: find / | grep libdb_cxx-4.8.so gives /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/ibdb_cxx-4.8.so

Comment: /home/*/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix/.libs/libdb_cxx-4.8.so
/home/*/litecoin/src/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix/.libs/libdb_cxx-4.8.so
/home/*/litecoin/src/qt/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix/.libs/libdb_cxx-4.8.so
/home/*/Desktop/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix/.libs/libdb_cxx-4.8.so

Comment: Run `ldd binary_name` and paste the result into the question, not as a comment. And what distribution and release are you running?

Comment: ldd libdb_cxx-4.8.so gives nothing..?

Comment: Your binary, not the library. Probably `ldd litecoin-qt` or similar. And if you want to notify someone, you need to do `@username` in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will be able to solve your problem:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib"
```

Comment: I pasted that into the terminal, then Cd'd into my litecoin directory, and i still have the same error, Error while loading shared libraries: libdb_cxx-4.8.so: cannot open shared object file

Comment: Hum i think that some required library for libdb is missing, run your program using gdb yourprogram and then do a 'run'.

Comment: Whenever i try to gdb run ./home/*/Desktop/litecoin-0.13.2/litecoin-qt =                           "No executable file specified"    Or gdb run ./litecoin-qt , it gives the same result

Comment: My litecoin-qt is also not recognised as a application, but as a "shared library"  "Type: shared library (application/x=shared..

Comment: Is just gdb /home/youruser/Desktop/litecoin-0.13.2/litecoin-qt  , after that you type the command "run" and then press enter.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed the issue now. It was because libdb was being overriden by a newer version i think? Either way thanks for your help

Comment: Probably you has a symlink pointed to it, and the newer version tried to write over the destination instead of the link.